# How do I make an Ajax request without uBlock Origin flagging it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipify.org',
    success: function(data){
        // alert(data);
        document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML = "Your IP is: " + data;
    }
})
```

It's pretty mundane code; just something to test if I can do more with custom HTML editing on my site; but I'm genuinely curious as to why this fails with uBlock enabled. It works fine with IE, Edge, Android Chrome, and desktop Chrome with uBlock disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The default EasyPrivacy list blocks ipify.org with this rule

```
||ipify.org^$third-party
```

So the long and short answer is really, it blocks it because it's blocked.

Comment: I guess I should have expected the obvious reason for why this wouldn't work. It's a bit strange that ipify is on that list though.